# ListView crashes on scroll Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` that is populated by a `JSONArray`. The data loads, but when I attempt to scroll, it crashes

Logcat:

```
09-19 11:50:53.512  15110-15110/io.moffat.kitchenpal E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
09-19 11:50:53.513  15110-15110/io.moffat.kitchenpal E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
09-19 11:50:53.514  15110-15110/io.moffat.kitchenpal E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:591)
            at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.refreshBitmapShader(CircularImageView.java:341)
            at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:262)
            at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:456)
            at com.squareup.picasso.PicassoDrawable.setPlaceholder(PicassoDrawable.java:61)
            at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:664)
            at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
            at io.moffat.kitchenpal.RecipeAdapter.getView(RecipeAdapter.java:87)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:662)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4991)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3418)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3801)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3632)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8471)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2399)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2092)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2369)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2330)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8666)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3989)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3737)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5807)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doPr
09-19 11:50:53.516  15110-15110/io.moffat.kitchenpal E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.moffat.kitchenpal, PID: 15110
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:591)
            at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.refreshBitmapShader(CircularImageView.java:341)
            at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:262)
            at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:456)
            at com.squareup.picasso.PicassoDrawable.setPlaceholder(PicassoDrawable.java:61)
            at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:664)
            at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
            at io.moffat.kitchenpal.RecipeAdapter.getView(RecipeAdapter.java:87)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:662)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4991)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3418)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3801)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3632)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8471)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2399)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2092)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2369)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2330)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8666)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3989)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3737)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEv
```

Activity with the Listview

```
class Populate extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(RecipeSearch.this, "Finding Recipes", "Searching....", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... urls) {
            JSONParser recipeParse = new JSONParser();
            String rawJSON = recipeParse.getJSON(urls[0]);

            try {

                if (rawJSON != null) {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(rawJSON);
                    JSONArray jArray = object.getJSONArray("recipes");
                    return jArray;
                } else {
                    JSONArray jArray = null;
                    return jArray;
                }

            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Searching for Recipes",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             JSONArray jArray = null;
                return jArray;
            }
            //do http request and add objects to array here.
            //need to do a custom adapter
           // return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jArray) {

            if (jArray != null) {
                final ListView recipes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recipeView);

                recipes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        JSONObject selected = (JSONObject) (recipes.getItemAtPosition(position));

                        String url = null;
                        try {
                            url = selected.getString("source_url");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                });

                recipeAdapter = new RecipeAdapter(RecipeSearch.this, jArray);//jArray is your json array
                recipes.setAdapter(recipeAdapter);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Recipes Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Adapter

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {


    private final Activity activity;
    private final JSONArray jsonArray;


    public RecipeAdapter (Activity activity, JSONArray jsonArray){
        assert activity !=null;
        assert jsonArray != null;

        this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
        this.activity = activity;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        if(null==jsonArray)
            return 0;
        else
            return jsonArray.length();
    }

    @Override
    public JSONObject getItem(int position){
        if(null==jsonArray) return null;
        else
        return jsonArray.optJSONObject(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View v, ViewGroup parent){
        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(activity, R.layout.recipe_item, null);
        }

        CircularImageView icon = (CircularImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.recipeIcon);
        TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.recipeTitle);
        TextView supplier = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.supplier);


        JSONObject JSdata = getItem(position);
        if(null!=JSdata){
            try {
                if (JSdata.has("title")) {
                    title.setText(JSdata.getString("title"));
                }
                if (JSdata.has("publisher")) {
                    supplier.setText(JSdata.getString("publisher"));
                }
                if (JSdata.has("image_url")){
                    String image = JSdata.getString("image_url");
                if (image != null) {
                    Picasso.with(activity)
                            .load(image)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .resize(50, 50)
                            .into(icon);
                }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Image not loaded",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        ImageView fav = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.favbutton);
        fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Fav",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }


}
```

I can't figure out why it's crashing. I assumed it was a JSON error based on similar questions, so I put in conditional checks to make sure that the JSONObject had the fields I was looking for.

Comment: try after passing context to adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not a `JSONException`. As you can see in Logs there is null reference to a `Bitmap` which upon calling `getWidth` throws an exception.

The only place I can see this can occur is in the following line:

```
Picasso.with(activity)
       .load(image)
       .centerCrop()
       .resize(50, 50)
       .into(icon);
```

You should check if you're feeding a valid url to `Picasso` cause if not, Picasso will throw an exception.

Comment: Ah, that might be it. I did put a check on that to ignore null values. Just traced through it and it seems to crash on image file formats that aren't .jpg, so that seems to be the way to go next. Thanks!

Comment: @jmo Sure, if this is your actual answer you may accept by clicking the check mark blow the points section.

Comment: Will do once it lets me!